# Cannot write functions in laravel config file

Tags: php, laravel, function

I have a dataset, and have set a config file for these fields and the change required for each field as function.

```
'email'        => [
    'column' => 'B',
    'change' => null,
    'field'  => 'users.email',
],
'license_type' => [
    'column' => 'C',
    'field'  => 'users.is_role',
    'change' => function ($value) {
        $roles = ["Licensed Teacher", "Licensed Coach", "Teacher's Trainer"];
        return $roles[$value];
    },
],
'date'         => [
    'column' => 'K',
    'field'  => 'webhook.start_date',
    'change' => function ($value) {
        return Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value)->toDateString();
    },
],
```

So to get the final value of a field, I apply its appropriate change function to the value.

All this works well but laravel throws an error when a function is defined in the config

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state() in /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/config.php on line 159

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You could adjust the contents of the `change` field to only contain the array. Then the implementation using that value should do the mapping from value to number

Comment: fml. That's just an example of the change function. It can be anything. I have updated the question please check

Comment: This is simply because Laravel tries to serialize the closure when it caches the config, and PHP doesn't allow it. There are various libraries available to allow it, but you might be better adding your functions to a class which manages the change for each type, then reference that class in your config.

Comment: @benJ Yeah thanks. Ended up doing just that

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your function to work as a nested array which can be referenced using the standard `config()` method. Then when you need a particular `change` value you can, call `config('license_type.change.0')` to get `"Licensed Teacher"` where `0` is the key for `"Licensed Teacher"` etc.

```
'email'        => [
    'column' => 'B',
    'change' => null,
    'field'  => 'users.email',
],
'license_type' => [
    'column' => 'C',
    'field'  => 'users.is_role',
    'change' => [
        "Licensed Teacher",
        "Licensed Coach", 
        "Teacher's Trainer"
    ],
],
```

Comment: fml. That's just an example of the change function. It can be anything. I have updated the question please check

Comment: Okay sorry for the misunderstanding, the config file shouldn't be used to store functions, just plain string or constants. It's misusing the file to store functions as values. See this issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7671, for more info. It's an old post but still relevant. I don't know where you would want to call your functions but they look like they would be better placed as model methods that reference the string values stored in the config file. e.g. You could use the `User` model to store a `license_type_change` method that returned these values.

Comment: Moving the change function to the model sounds bad to me because then the related logic will be spread out at different places. You know, I had implemented it exactly like this in lumen and it didn't give an issue.

Comment: Yeah. I don't like it when related code is at different places, making the project more confusing. If I even had to do it your way, I think its better to write only one change method that sanitizes as per each field.

Comment: Okay I've found a solution to your question, but for the record I think you could refactor your logic here to work outside of the config file. You can successfully reference the `change` functions you've created like so: `config('app.license_types.change')('1')` where `config('app.license_types.change')` returns the change function and `('1')` defines you passing in `'1'` as the `$value` argument. I've tested this on Laravel 6 and it works as desired. If this doesn't work then try clearing your config cache with `php artisan config:clear` in the command line

Comment: That is the exact way that I have done it and it doesn't work. As soon as I run php artisan config:cache, artisan breaks and returns that error. Does it throw an error for you too?